# Angular js and API testing using protractor and jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am testing AngularJS application which is dependent on API and I am new to do API testing. I login to page which is AngularJS app. When I login it calls api I am able to test UI stuffs but now I need to test API.

For example UI code, I am using page object:

```
 LoginPage.setUserName('test@test.com');
 LoginPage.setPassWord('test');
 LoginPage.clickButton();
```

This code works fine, on click of submit button it calls API to process the login. Now I need to test that API call:

On click it calls:

```
GET https://192.168.00.00:0000/config/settings.json
```

with response:

```
{
    "domain": "https://192.168.000.00",
    "port":1111
}
```

and then it calls:

```
POST https://192.168.000.00:1111/api/Login
```

with response:

```
{
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "message":"Login Successful",
    "results: {
        "id":96,
        "userName":"test@test.com",
        "password":null,
        "firstName":"Test",
        "lastName":"Testing",
        "employeeCode":"007",
        "location":2
    }
}
```

Now I need to test this scenario with mocking it. I wrote this mocking code:

```
exports.signup_request = function() {

    angular.module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E']).run(function($httpBackend) { 
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/Login/').respond({
            "status":"SUCCESS",
            "message":"Login Successful",
            "results": {
                "id":96,
                "userName":"test@test.com",
                "password":null,
                "firstName":"test",
                "lastName":"Testing",
                "employeeCode":"007",
                "location":2
            }
        });
        // allow views directory to go to real $http
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/views\//).passThrough();
        // we have a real /api/customer service, let it through
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/^/api/Login//).passThrough();
    });
}
```

My spec file which loads mock js file where I have written `$httpBackend`       related code:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    mockModule = require('./mock');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;     
});

it("ensure user can signup for the application", function(){
    browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock',   mockModule.signup_request);
    // DONT NO WHAT TO WRITE HERE;
});
```

When I run this spec it shows `browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', mockModule.signup_request);` is undefined.